# Consistent CSS Div Background Height

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble keeping a consistent Background image height on a div across multiple devices, I am using Chrome's DevTools to preview the outcome on different devices based on their width. Let me explain further.

I have a div with the following class...

```
.header-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 57%;
        background: url('img/fruit-water.jpg') lightgrey;
        background-size: 100%;
        display: block;
}
```

This displays perfectly fine on the normal computer viewport, the `height: 57%;` property displays the perfect amount of the background image that I need. But when I change the view onto another device it doesn't display the same amount of the image that it initially did, it only shows about 20% of the image.

Does anyone know a way to keep the amount of the image displayed consistent, even with the width value changing?

I can't use Jquery or any plugins as the page is an AMP page and validates according to the AMP rules set by google.

https://jsfiddle.net/pre6L7d9/1 <-- Fiddle, Please look into it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots or fiddle?
What if you use "background-size: cover" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @severinolorillajr said you can use:

```
background-size:cover;
```

and if you want to center it to the top you can use:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position:50% 0%;
```

EDIT:
Sorry i cannot answer the other question,

if you want to use a % height like 57% you need to set the image position:absolute;

Or you can use:

```
height:57vh;
```

That will do the trick!

EDIT2:

maybe you need to mantain the image scale, then you need to set it to:

```
height:57vw;
```

Comment: Using position absolute throws everything else in the page out of whack

Comment: with height:57vw; you don't need position absolute! there's your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pre6L7d9/2/

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked, can you explain the vw to me?

Comment: vh means Viewport Height, vw means Viewport Width

Comment: So the height of the div box background is now relative to the width of the viewport right? Atleast thats what i understand but thats what i needed either way thank you it seems to be working!

Comment: Yes its that! by the way it works on IE9+, but nowdays that's not a problem i think

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-image { 
    background: url('img/fruit-water.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Check this for other CSS Implementation](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: For some reason this is removing the div from the page now, unless the div box is populated

Comment: While this is a correct answer note that this css-tricks article is from **2010**. `background-size` doesn't need vendor prefixes anymore.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius try adding the background on `<html>` tag... RIght thanks for bringing that up @Demnogonis..

Comment: @severinolorillajr it works but as i said when the width value changes the image scales to the width meaning that 300px down the page is not what it was with the initial width value because the image has been scaled.

I cannot use a % value either or else the div does not display unless populated